# What's the meaning of 角刈り in this context?

Tags: translation, words, meaning

I came across this sentence:

冗談はその角刈りだけにしてくださいよ

(Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1e-WwxCZ3w)

From the context, I reckon it means "Please don't joke /Give me a break", but I'm stumped by 角刈り. My dictionary says 角刈り = a crew cut (haircut), which makes no sense here. Is this some sort of slang/idiom?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you're pretty much right.  The literal translation would be "Let the only joke be your crew cut (or hairstyle) and I would localize it to something like "The only joke here is your hair." Basically, the speaker is mocking his target's hairstyle.

It should be noted that usually this line isn't used with 角刈り, but with 顔, as in 「冗談は顔だけにしてくれ」(thus taking a jab at someone's looks).